# SystemD Setup Can't Find Python?

Tags: python, unix, amazon-ec2, systemd

I have a cronjob running on AWS EC2, that I usually launch via crontab:

```
0 */6 * * * sudo python3 /opt/homeDirectoryForMyApp/manage.py myCronJob --settings=server.settings.production
```

This works correctly as expected. Now I'm trying to launch the same job via SystemD.

**myCronJob.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=myCronJob Service
Wants=myCronJob.timer

[Service]
ExecStart='/usr/bin/python3.7' manage.py myCronJob --settings=server.settings.production
WorkingDirectory=/opt/homeDirectoryForMyApps/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**myCronJob.timer:**

```
[Unit]
Description=launch myCronJob
Requires=myCronJob.service

[Timer]
Unit=myCronJob.service
OnCalendar=00/2:10

[Install]
WantedBy=rss.target
```

I'm getting this in journalctl (via `journalctl -u myCronJob`):

```
Jan 02 22:45:03 ip-###-##-#-### systemd[3760]: myCronJob.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/python3.7: No such file or directory
```

But `/usr/bin/python3.7` does exist at that path:

```
ubuntu@ip-###-##-#-###:/etc/systemd/system$ cd /usr/bin

ubuntu@ip-###-##-#-###:/usr/bin$ ls python3.7 
python3.7
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It says "Failed at step CHDIR". Are you sure you have specified `WorkingDirectory` correctly?

Comment: Is that the directory where "manage.py" is located? If so then yes.

Comment: I ask because you've spelled it `homeDirectoryForMyApp` in your crontab, and `homeDirectoryForMyApps` in the unit file. If you could replace the expurgated version of your crontab and unit file with what you're *actually* using, it would be easier to tell if this is a typo or something else.

Comment: You are right! I had that same typo in my actual config file. That solves that error. Thanks! If you'd like to post it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is:

```
Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/python3.7: No such file or directory
```

This suggests that the problem actually lies with your `WorkingDirectory` setting in your unit file (`step CHDIR` means "the error occurred when trying to change directory").

There is probably a typo in your `WorkingDirectory` path in your unit file.